# Storing and retrieving users' favorite tags

Tags: mongodb, analytics, nosql

I'm trying to implement a behavioral analysis for targeted marketing on my ecommerce website. The basic idea is as follows (I assume the usage of MongoDB, but looking forward for the other recommendations):

- every website `Category` has a list of associated `tags` to it,
- every content `Article` also has a list of `tags`,
- every `User` has an unique cookie ID assigned to him/her on the first visit,
- every time the user browses a `Category` or reads an `Article`, we plan to increment the `User-tag` dictionary like this:

  ```
  db.tagviews.update(
      {_id: user_id},
      {$inc: {'tags.foo': 1, 'tags.bar': 1, 'tags.baz': 1}},
      true /* upsert */
  )
  ```

So if we want to see the interests of the particular user, we can fetch the `tagviews` document for him and look through the `tags` to see which ones has the most views.

However, I've stumbled on a pretty much trivial thing - how to fetch users, based on tags criteria. E.g. we've got Google Galaxy Nexus in stock for an attractive price, and want to send marketing emails to the users most interested in `[android, phones, gadgets, google]`.

As far as I understand, we have to create indexes on every `tags.*` field in the tagviews collection, which is, of course, unacceptable. The other possible solution is to duplicate data in another dimension (incrementing tag-user combo instead of user-tag). But syntetic tests looks very unpromising in terms of disk space and flexibility.

What would be your suggestions to effectively fetch the most interested users based on tags criteria?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example i understand that you are using tag names as keys (aka fields) in tagviews collection.

**Dont do that** , which leaves you in the nightmare when you need to create indexes. Instead create tags as embedded doc within tagviews

```
 tagviews{
      _id : 'xxxx',
      tags : [
        {
           name : "foo",
           count : 0
        },
        {
           name : "bar",
           count : 0
        },
        {
           name : "baz",
           count : 0
        }   
      ]
```

and you can effectively  index this document by tag name to use it in your filters

```
db.tagviews.ensureIndex('tags.name',1)
```

And you can increment the specific tag view of a user by

```
db.tagviews.update({_id : "userid" , "tags.name":'foo'},{$inc:{"tags.$.count":1}})
```

when your user stumbled on his interests.

So to your real question,

> how to fetch users, based on tags criteria. E.g. we've got Google
>   Galaxy Nexus in stock for an attractive price, and want to send
>   marketing emails to the users most interested in [android, phones,
>   gadgets, google].

you can filter it like

```
 db.tagviews.find({'tags.name':{$in : ['android', 'phones','gadgets','google'] }})
```

This will retrieve all the users who are interested in above said tags.

or even you can use count to filter most accurate data

```
db.tagviews.find({'tags.name':{$in : ['android', 'phones','gadgets','google'] },'tags.count' : {$gt : 0 }})
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I kinda missed the `$` operator. The only downside is that I will have to issue an update for every tag I need to update (because $ matches only first occurence). With tag-as-key it would be just 1 update.

Comment: yes, indeed. there is a open issue where using [https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243]($ positional operator in update all matching embedded docs). when this is ready you can use it like `db.tagviews.update({_id : "userid" , "tags.name":{$in : ['foo','bar','baz']}},{$inc:{"tags.$.count":1}})`

Comment: FYI, I made a few tests and stopped on the `tags.tagname: count` option. While it may be bad for a certain use cases, I use sparse indexes to index on these fields. Tag count will be reasonably low (e.g. < 10000), so the index overhead is ok. The main reason for this was that $-operator does not support upsert on non-existent doc, so I would have to double-check user-document existence on every request.